# Como salvar muitos arrays em um mesmo txt em Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, txt

Olá!
Tenho um codigo em Python3 e em cada looping ele gera 5 arrays do tipo coluna. 
Para o primeiro looping eu consegui gravar cada array como uma coluna em um txt usando o numpy.savetxt:

```py
array_aux1[int(j/tau), 0] = scale
array_aux2[int(j/tau), 0] = j
array_aux3[int(j/tau), 0] = spectrum_gapped[i]
array_aux4[int(j/tau), 0] = np.real(coef_gapped)
array_aux5[int(j/tau), 0] = np.imag(coef_gapped)

if i == 1:       
    np.savetxt("teste.txt", 
               np.hstack([array_aux1, array_aux2, array_aux3, array_aux4, array_aux5]), 
               fmt = ["%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e"],
               delimiter = '\t' 
     )
```

O problema é que eu quero abrir esse arquivo novamente para todos os "i's" do looping e primeiro adicionar uma linha em branco e depois salvar os novos arrays gerados. Tentei continuar o condicional abrindo o arquivo "teste.txt" com o parâmetro "append" e usar novamente o np.savetxt:

```py
else:
    file = open("teste.txt", "a")
    file.write('\n')
    np.savetxt("teste.txt", 
               np.hstack([array_aux1, array_aux2, array_aux3, array_aux4, array_aux5]), 
               fmt = ["%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e"], 
               delimiter = '\t' 
    )
```

O que acontece é que as matrizes anteriores não são preservadas. Não acontece a inserção da linha em branco e nem a preservação dos resultados anteriores. O que fazer nesse caso? Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Comment: Às pessoas colocando "downvote" nesta pergunta, eu gostaria de saber o motivo.

Comment: Eu também não entendi porque minha pergunta está recebendo esses "downvotes". Mas isso é incomum por aqui. Logo alguém responde e ajuda!@

Comment: ao contário, não tem sido incomum - alguns usuários aparentemente  estão com o mindset de "nossa eu não sei responder isso - então vou dar downvote". A ideia da minha pergunta acima é que as pessoas percebam o que estão fazendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe que apesar de você abrir  arquivo com `"a"` no segundo acesso, você não está passando o arquivo que você abriu (que está na variável `file`) para a função `savetxt` do numpy - em vez disso, você passa só o nome do arquivo.

E o comportamento do numpy.savetxt nesse caso é criar um novo arquivo do zero, ignorando qualquer conteúdo anterior. (Em sistemas Unix como o Linux e MacOS X, o arquivo existente na variável `file` vai continuar acessível a partir do seu programa, e você pode continuar lendo e escrevendo nele no seu programa, mas ele não estará mais acessível no sistema de arquivos).

Bom, finalizando: a função `savetxt` aceita no primeiro parâmetro objetos do tipo arquivo abertos, e não só strings com nome de arquivos. Então no seu caso, basta fazer a chamada passando `file` em vez de "teste.txt" que você chegará ao resultado desejado.

```
       np.savetxt(file, np.hstack([
           array_aux1, array_aux2, array_aux3,array_aux4, array_aux5]),
           fmt = ["%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e", "%.5e"], delimiter = '\t' 
       )
```

---

nota: a não ser que você vá usar esse txt como um tipo  de "relatório" para ser visuaizado diretamente por pessoas, o formato txt não é a melhor forma de preservar esses dados, para envio para outra aplicação, por exemplo. Se os dados vão ser processados depois em um programa Python mesmo, o melhor é usar o módulo `pickle` para salvar esses dados: não é legível para humanos, mas todos os atributos dos objetos são preservados e recuperados de forma transparente.

Comment: muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente. Eu preciso que saia exatamente neste formato porque depois esse txt (que em geral fica gigante) é usado como Input para o Gnuplot gerar um gráfico via linha de comando. Nem me atrevo a abrir ele rs. Mas vou ler sobre esse módulo pickle para ver ser consigo em breve me entender com o matplotlib e gerar um gráfico semelhante em Python usando esses dados. Abraço!